# merge xml matching attributes value

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I'm trying to merge two xml files by matching the value of an attribute.
xml files come from mysql queries with '--xml' output.

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="SELECT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <row>
   <field name="ID_editore">20</field>
   <field name="nome">Name1</field>
   <field name="biografia">Bib1</field>
   <field name="autoricat"></field>
 </row>
 <row>
   <field name="ID_editore">21</field>
   <field name="nome">Name2</field>
   <field name="biografia">Bib2</field>
   <field name="autoricat">text2</field>
 </row>
</resultset>
```

file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset statement="SELECT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <row>
  <field name="editore_ID">20</field>
  <field name="data">1929</field>
  <field name="indirizzo">Address 1</field>
</row>
 <row>
  <field name="editore_ID">21</field>
  <field name="data">1950</field>
  <field name="indirizzo">Address 2</field>
 </row>
</resultset>
```

Desired Merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" statement="SELECT">
 <row>
  <field name="ID_editore">20</field>
  <field name="nome">Name1</field>
  <field name="biografia">Bib1</field>
  <field name="autoricat"/>
  <field name="data">1929</field>
  <field name="indirizzo">Address 1</field>
 </row>
 <row>
  <field name="ID_editore">21</field>
  <field name="nome">Name2</field>
  <field name="biografia">Bib2</field>
  <field name="autoricat">text2</field>
  <field name="data">1950</field>
  <field name="indirizzo">Address 2</field>
 </row>
</resultset>
```

With the following stylesheet I get the wrong result, because I don't know how to match the right attribute values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />

     <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')
            /resultset/row/field[(@name='editore_ID')=current()[@name='ID_editore']]"/>

    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wrong result with above stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" statement="SELECT">
 <row>
    <field name="ID_editore">20</field>
    <field name="nome">Name1</field>
    <field name="biografia">Bib1</field>
    <field name="autoricat"/>
    <field name="data">1929</field>
    <field name="indirizzo">Address 1</field>
    <field name="data">1950</field>
    <field name="indirizzo">Address 2</field>
   </row>
   <row>
    <field name="ID_editore">21</field>
    <field name="nome">Name2</field>
    <field name="biografia">Bib2</field>
    <field name="autoricat">text2</field>
    <field name="data">1929</field>
    <field name="indirizzo">Address 1</field>
    <field name="data">1950</field>
    <field name="indirizzo">Address 2</field>
   </row>
  </resultset>
```

I run this command to get the output

```
xsltproc stylesheet.xsl file1.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following XPath expression in your `xsl:copy-of` :

```
document('file2.xml.xml')
    /resultset
    /row
    /field[
        @name='editore_ID' and .=current()/field[@name='ID_editore']
    ]
    /following-sibling::field
```

The XPath first finds `editore_ID` which value matches current `ID_editore`, and then returns all the following sibling `field` elements (so that the `editore_ID` itself is not copied to the output XML).